# How to extend Ellipse class in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, class, extend, ellipse

It is a short question. For example I want to add a field `double weight` to my ellipse. How can I do this?

*Sorry for 2 copies of comment*

Comment: What did you try? You need to add a field of type double called "weight" to a class derived from Ellipse. If you have problems doing so, post some code.

Comment: [`Ellipse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.ellipse.aspx) is `sealed`, you can't extend it. What sort of "weight" are you talking about, e.g.: how it's displayed, or the idea of a physical mass?

Comment: You could also use [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) instead of subclassing.

Comment: Actually, I have a program, which works with Nodes and Arches, now I have a List<Node> nodeList and Ellipse. But it is too massively and logically wrong. Can you give me some example of code, where you attaching property to Ellipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of situation, I create a class where one attribute is the Ellipse and the other attributes are the attributes I want to add to the ellipse class. This is a bit dirty but it allows to have a class that contains all the Ellipse features as well as my additional attributes.

```
class WeightedEllipse
{
public Ellipse ellipse;
public double weight;

public WeightedEllipse(double weight)
    {
      this.ellipse=new Ellipse();
      this.weight=weight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to [`System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.ellipse.aspx) then you cannot extend the class - it is `sealed`. However you could use a [custom attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) to add your weight information.

Something along the lines of the following: (in a "`HelperClass`")

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty WeightProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
  "Weight",
  typeof(double),
  typeof(HelperClass),
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0)
);

public static void SetWeight(Ellipse element, double value){
  element.SetValue(WeightProperty, value);
}

public static double GetWeight(Ellipse element) {
  return (double)element.GetValue(WeightProperty);
}
```

and then later

```
HelperClass.SetWeight(ellipseInstance, 42d)
```

If `Ellipse` is your own class (and not a 
`DependencyObject`), then of course extending should not be an issue and we would require more information to help you.

Comment: Actually, I have a program, which works with Nodes and Arches, now I have a List<Node> nodeList and Ellipse. But it is too massively and logically wrong. Can you give me some example of code, where you attaching property to Ellipse?